# creating objects with attributes from a text file

Tags: python-3.x

Im making a program that reads the info of some football teams from a textile(named `30eapril.txt`) and uses this data when creating some team-objects. I wonder how I can make the program read the number of teams in the textile and create objects of them. The code I've written so far works but has a lot of repetitive parts!

```
class team: 
    def __init__(self, teamdata):
        self.name = teamdata[0]
        self.wins = teamdata[1]
        self.drawn = teamdata[2]
        self.losses = teamdata[3]
    def __repr__(self): 
        return self.name.ljust(15) + '{} {} {}'.format(self.wins, self.drawn, self.losses)

laglista = []
with open('30eapril.txt', 'rt') as file:
    for line in file:
        laglista.append(line)

team1data = (laglista[0]).split()
team2data = (laglista[1]).split()
team3data = (laglista[2]).split()
team4data = (laglista[3]).split()

lag1 = team(team1data) 
lag2 = team(team2data)
lag3 = team(team3data)
lag4 = team(team4data)

print(lag1) 
print(lag2)
print(lag3)
print(lag4)
```

this is what was in the textfile

```
Arsenal        2 1 0 
Manchester     2 0 0 
Liverpool      0 1 2 
Newcastle      0 0 2
```

Hope that someone can help! 
//Peter

Comment: You seem to know about lists; why not try using them?

Comment: Well I did try to make a list out of "teamdata" but when I tried to put  teamdata[0] as an argument creating a team object I got the answer "TypeError: 'list' object is not callable"

Comment: Can't really comment on code I can't see, but are you sure you didn't use `teamdata(0)` instead of `teamdata[0]` by mistake?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Shortened code: (could certainly be even better)

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

class team: 
    def __init__(self, teamdata):
        self.name, self.wins, self.drawn, self.losses = teamdata
    def __repr__(self): 
        return self.name.ljust(15) + '{} {} {}'.format(self.wins, self.drawn, self.losses)

lag = []
with open('30eapril.txt', 'rt') as file:
    for line in file:
        lag.append(team(line.split()))

#print("Number of teams: " + str(len(lag)))
for l in lag:
    print(l)
```

You don't need to know the number of lines of your file.

With the same content of '30eapril.txt', the output is:

```
$ ./test_script3.py
Arsenal        2 1 0
Manchester     2 0 0
Liverpool      0 1 2
Newcastle      0 0 2
```

Same script on '30eapril.txt' having a extra line:

```
$ ./test_script3.py
Arsenal        2 1 0
Manchester     2 0 0
Liverpool      0 1 2
Newcastle      0 0 2
AnotherClub    1 0 2
```